# Attribute `marker-mid` doesn't work when drawing an cubic bezier path

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working on an graph drawing program currently. When I was writing codes, I decided to drew rings with cubic bezier path to those self-connected edge, and drew common ellipse arcs on edges that connected to other nodes. Besides, I was going to add labels to these edge using `marker-mid` attribute. But something quirky appeared, that **the label doen't shown up on the self-connected edge (cubic bezier curve path), but it could show correctly on the edge that conntected to other nodes (ellipse arc path).** I have been searched on the web for a while, but none of relative answers can solve my problem. I hope someone could tells me the reason. I will be very aappreciated.

Here is the code of marker. (Vue template)

```
<marker
  :id="edge-label-marker-${edge.id}" 
  markerWidth='100'
  markerHeight='9'
  viewBox="-10 -20 40 30"
  refX="0"
  refY='10'
  orient='0'
  markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
    <text text-anchor="middle">example label</text>
</marker>
```

and the code of `path`

```
 <path :d='linkArc(edge)' :marker-mid="url(#edge-label-marker-${edge.id})"/>
```

Besides here are the codes that produce actual path of the curve:

```
function _getRingPath (x, y) {
  var len = 300;
  var controlPoints = {
    left: { x: x - len, y: y - len },
    right: { x: x + len, y: y - len },
  };

  return `
    M ${x},${y}
    C ${controlPoints.left.x},${controlPoints.left.y} 
      ${controlPoints.right.x},${controlPoints.right.y}
      ${x},${y}`
}
```

```
function _getArcPath (sourceX, sourceY, targetX, targetY) {
  var dx = sourceX - targetX
  var dy = sourceY - targetY
  var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  return `
    M ${sourceX}, ${sourceY}
    A ${dr},${dr} 0 0,1 ${targetX},${targetY}`
}
```

And finially, there is an example image that show the missing label.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The marker-mid should be rendered on every vertex other than the first and last vertices of the path data.
As you can see next it appears where it is supposed to apear.

```css
path{stroke:black; fill:none}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 200">
<marker
  id="edge-label-marker" 
  markerWidth='100'
  markerHeight='9'
  viewBox="-10 -20 40 30"
  refX="0"
  refY='10'
  orient='0'
  markerUnits='strokeWidth'>
    <text text-anchor="middle">example label</text>
</marker>
<path d="M10,95 C25,15 105,10 125,95 C145,180 225,185 240,95" marker-mid="url(#edge-label-marker)"/>
</svg>
```